AttributeError: 'res.config.settings' object has no attribute 'get_debranding_settings'
when I try to restore the odoo database I found the error
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/beyondex/odoo15/odoo/addons/http_routing/models/ir_http.py", line 672, in _handle_exception
    code, html = cls._get_error_html(env, code, values)
  File "/home/beyondex/odoo15/odoo/addons/website/models/ir_http.py", line 415, in _get_error_html
    return super(Http, cls)._get_error_html(env, code, values)
  File "/home/beyondex/odoo15/odoo/addons/http_routing/models/ir_http.py", line 617, in _get_error_html
    return code, env['ir.ui.view']._render_template('http_routing.%s' % code, values)
  File "/home/beyondex/odoo15/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 1992, in _render_template
    return self.browse(self.get_view_id(template))._render(values, engine)
  File "/home/beyondex/odoo15/odoo/addons/website/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 435, in _render
    return super(View, self)._render(values, engine=engine, minimal_qcontext=minimal_qcontext)
  File "/home/beyondex/odoo15/odoo/addons/web_editor/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 29, in _render
    return super(IrUiView, self)._render(values=values, engine=engine, minimal_qcontext=minimal_qcontext)
  File "/home/beyondex/odoo15/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 2000, in _render
    return self.env[engine]._render(self.id, qcontext)
  File "/home/beyondex/odoo15/odoo/odoo/tools/profiler.py", line 292, in _tracked_method_render
    return method_render(self, template, values, **options)
  File "/home/beyondex/odoo15/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_qweb.py", line 76, in _render
    result = super()._render(template, values=values, **compile_options)
  File "/home/beyondex/odoo15/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/qweb.py", line 134, in _render
    result = ''.join(rendering)
  File "/home/beyondex/odoo15/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/qweb.py", line 221, in render_template
    raise e
  File "/home/beyondex/odoo15/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/qweb.py", line 219, in render_template
    yield from compiled_fn(self, values, log)
  File "<template_248>", line 20, in template_248
  File "/home/beyondex/odoo15/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/qweb.py", line 223, in render_template
    raise QWebException("Error when render the template", self, options,
odoo.addons.base.models.qweb.QWebException: 'res.config.settings' object has no attribute 'get_debranding_settings'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/beyondex/odoo15/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/qweb.py", line 219, in render_template
    yield from compiled_fn(self, values, log)
  File "<template_186>", line 363, in template_186
AttributeError: 'res.config.settings' object has no attribute 'get_debranding_settings'

Error when render the template
AttributeError: 'res.config.settings' object has no attribute 'get_debranding_settings'
Template: web.frontend_layout
Path: /t/html/head/t[7]
Node: <t t-set="favicon_url" t-value="request.env['res.config.settings'].sudo().get_debranding_settings()['favicon_url']"/>


Search in your custom addons (src/user ?) which module contains get_debranding_settings. And reinstall it before importing your database.
Alternatively you could look in your database_restore file and comment the involved lines:
<!--t t-set="favicon_url" t-value="request.env['res.config.settings'].sudo().get_debranding_settings()['favicon_url']"/-->

or set the attribute active=False for their corresponding view.
